# How to fix clipping knee joint with ik bones?

Tags: mesh, rigging, bones, pose-mode, inverse-kinematics

I created a quadruped character, and added ik bones to the legs, but the problem is the knees start clipping when it bends. i tried to see if changing the weight paint would help, but it just got worse. How can i make the knees bend softly, without clipping?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: First, use Google Images to look for pictures of "knee topology".  Then, look up "corrective shapekey" techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried the following things and it seems to work:

- Enable the *Armature* modifier's *Preserve Volume* option
- I've added an edge loop above the joint:

[image]

- I've segmented the small bone:

[image]

- I've extended a bit its influence upwards in *Weight Paint* mode, use *Mix, Substract*, use also the *Blur* brush:

[image]

- And I've extended a bit the influence of the top leg downwards:

[image]

A try with 2.79, I 've added a *Pole Target* to make it bend correctly:

[image]

Comment: I did everything, and nothing changed: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-Fp9WLdr2v8w/YAFB87LLJGI/AAAAAAAAGOU/DRtR7_QWRCov_6XHNJmgPqPMhf0Zf2MGQCLcBGAsYHQ/s320/22222.png https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-2bRgsOEBSKY/YAFB8-eSTLI/AAAAAAAAGOM/dGnhM5MIRQ02hWGFsEYhYZY9Qt1V_T6gQCLcBGAsYHQ/s320/11112.png https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-NZAOC97QNpg/YAFB88u7EAI/AAAAAAAAGOQ/DWj-0r_UZ9ETCwmlPeQN90AoMWriIxPTgCLcBGAsYHQ/s320/3366.png https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9EgMxNQ4yKc/YAFB9R8W6kI/AAAAAAAAGOY/pSd5A4epNDQHi-JApL6UDgurjgWuZtf4wCLcBGAsYHQ/s320/hhhhhh.png

Comment: see the third capture, I've extended the weight painting higher. Here is the file: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=LABNN1GS" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/LABNN1GS/)

Comment: extend the weight on this part: https://zupimages.net/up/21/02/pap5.jpg

Comment: i can't open the file on blender 2.79, i extended the wheight paint of the bone, nothing changed again: https://i.ibb.co/QmPgBMB/33333.png, and then i extended a bit more and nothing changed, it keeps clipping https://i.ibb.co/ByyfSWQ/4444.png

Comment: you should be able to append the objects, but maybe share the new file

Comment: Here is teh file [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=OzO7W0qQ" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/OzO7W0qQ/)

Comment: I worked on your file with 2.8 and it seems to work, you need to add or substract weight painting for each bone until it bend nicely, also enable the Armature modifier's Preserve Volume option, I'm going to try in 2.79 but I think it doesn't make any difference

Comment: See my edit, I've given a try with 2.79, a bit harder to work I don't know why but it should work fine

Comment: Thanks, i'll try creating the pole bone, i tried it before some days ago and didn't worked well, but i'll change the weight paint or edit the mesh to get the result.